# How to read ASCII control characters from INI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ascii, ini

I'm calling the following native API to read/write from INI files

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(    // INI Read
        String section,
        String key,
        String def,
        StringBuilder retVal,
        int size,
        String filePath);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(  // INI Write
        String section,
        String key,
        String val,
        String filePath);

public string ReadIni(string sectionString, string keyString, string filePathString) 
{
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(200000);
    int i = GetPrivateProfileString(sectionString, keyString, "", temp, temp.Capacity, filePathString);
    return temp.ToString();
}

        // Write (Section, Key, Data, File Path)
public void WriteIni(
string sectionString, string keyString, string dataString, string filePathString) 
{
    WritePrivateProfileString(sectionString, keyString, dataString, filePathString);
}
```

Reading/Writing to ini files works well with the above code.

When I try to read ASCII control chars, such as 0x02 (STX) and 0x03 (ETX), read function just returns an empty string. Writing the control characters works perfectly.

Normally, I'd just avoid using native APIs to read/write into INI or better yet, avoid using ini files altogether, but this is a really old legacy application I'm fixing so that that I need to get this function to work in its current form.

How can I make GetPrivateProfileString read ASCII control characters?

Comment: The INI file format has some minimal syntax requirements.  Control characters are not supported, just plain text is required.  And that better be ASCII encoded text, it is too primitive to properly support Unicode encodings and you'll get junk if you use extended characters and the code page doesn't match.  Relying on INI files is a mistake in general, it is also ridiculously slow to read a setting due to the appcompat.

Comment: @HansPassant I absolutely agree. This is a legacy application I'm supporting, and well the decision is made way over my head so I don't have a choice unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I think problem at writing to ini. You must use that code writing to ini file :

```
//Writing to ini file

string pFileName = "test.ini"
string W_Text = "[" + pSection + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                                 pKey + "=" + pDefValue;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pFileName, W_Text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

You can read from ini file above codes :

```
//Reading from ini file

pFileName="test.ini";
IniDocument W_Ini = new IniDocument(pFileName, IniFileType.WindowsStyle);
IConfigSource W_Source = new IniConfigSource(W_Ini);
return W_Source.Configs[pSection].Get(pKey);
```

Comment: To work this codes we must add to reference as nugget Nini. (Right click References from Solution Explorer. Manage Nuget Packages --> Search Nini --> install "Trove Unofficial Nini Configuration" )